# not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: matlab, image-processing, svm, libsvm

Help i am having trouble using this matlab command. I am trying to use the SVM train using matlab with this command

svmOutFile = [prefix '/svmOut.dat'];

command = ['!libsvm-2.88\windows\svm-train.exe -t 0 -c ' num2str(c) ' -v ' num2str(n) ' ' trainFile ' > ' svmOutFile];

eval(command);

where the error is 'libsvm-2.88\windows\svm-train.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

What should i do?

Comment: next time just google "is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file". Therer are thousands of solutions to that problem online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your system cannot find that executable as you did not provide a complete path and it is not part of the PATH environment variable.

> libsvm-2.88\windows\svm-train.exe

Is not a valid path. You are missing at least a drive letter, if not more.

Provide the full path or add that path to your PATH.